# Determining which GeoServer version is running?

Tags: geoserver, getcapabilities

Is there a way to find out which version of [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) is running from any standard document such as `GetCapabilities`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the page http://you.server/geoserver/web/

There it should say something like:

"This GeoServer instance is running version x.x.x."

If your question was how to do it programmatically, most languages has a way to send a http-request and interpret the response to locate a string like "This GeoServer instance is running version x.x.x"

Comment: If you don't have access to the web interface, is there another way to get information about the version?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on how you have installed it I guess. I've installed on tomcat, and then I can see the version under <tomcat-dir>/webapps/geoserver/META-INF/maven/org.geoserver.web/web-app/pom.xml

Comment: @Plux I think Chau asked for a way to request the installed version from a remote client.

Comment: @JJD That could be, but if he does not have access to the server (via for example ssh or the web interface), how is he supposed to contact the server to get the version? I interpreted it such as the web service is not working (for some reason - perhaps an error?) and he needs to find the version to post an error report or get help - or something. :)

Comment: @Plux True. I myself was searching for a programmatic way to retrieve the version such as from an API call via HTTP. The webinterface is at least one solution one could work with. Thx.

Answer (score 6):

In more recent versions of GeoServer you can also get the [version (and other information)](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/1.0.0/manifests.yaml) via the REST API using a call like:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/about/version.xml
```

which will return:

```
<about>
  <resource name="GeoServer">
    <Build-Timestamp>21-Nov-2017 22:02</Build-Timestamp>
    <Version>2.12.1</Version>
    <Git-Revision>5927e49e781ddcdbf9213d32a439418347c17480</Git-Revision>
  </resource>
  <resource name="GeoTools">
    <Build-Timestamp>21-Nov-2017 14:18</Build-Timestamp>
    <Version>18.1</Version>
    <Git-Revision>306cf3bdde1bee0110dc1c3ba77819f1e294a45b</Git-Revision>
  </resource>
  <resource name="GeoWebCache">
    <Version>1.12.1</Version>
    <Git-Revision>1.12.x/22d18b47c9e80316d563c28d280602cb3dde624c</Git-Revision>
  </resource>
</about>
```

Comment: works for logged in user only: `curl -u user:password http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/about/version.xml`

Comment: yes, all of the REST API requires authentication

Answer (score -2):

Yes, to contribute on that:
PLease, look at the left menu: "About GeoServer" , there is exact info on your Geoserver build, like:

```
Version
2.8
Build Date
17-Jan-2016 21:47
```